# Dialog goes up when softkeyboard is shown

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard

I have a class that extends `Dialog`. In that `Dialog` I have an `EditText` and a `ListView`. I can bring soft keyboard up when that dialog is shown. But my problem is can we make dialog not to go up when soft keyboard is shown? I tried to change `softInputMode` in layout params to adjust resize but it's not working. My `Dialog` uses x and y position, when soft keyboard is shown and dialog goes up, my dialog is not in the position I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want it to resize and not just shift up use:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

This will also let you scroll within the dialog