# Keyboard closing the edit text

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment with an edit text in it. I set the height,width of a dialog fragment using -

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout((int)(width * 0.8),(int)(height * 0.8));
    }
```

The problem is that when I click on edittext of the dialog fragment, the key board appears and closes the edittext and I cannot see what I am typing. To see what I have typed, I have to close the keyboard. How do I make my dialog fragment adjust when the keyboard opens up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635783/dialog-goes-up-when-softkeyboard-is-shown

Comment: I saw this link but it is not helping me

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried this: `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`. You can add this to your EditText. I hope that solves your problem.